# Are Tales of Zestiria and Tales of Berseria connected in any way?

Tags: tales-of-zestiria, tales-of-berseria

In a Funimation email I got ([web version](http://view.em.funimation.com/?qs=e790ba1e89b120a66cdb33fe53d332a8816502971da3efed162929c203c293ce352894cc7c48f1a786c9cd251036a7c6ad9244540a84098bb2453b8204b901f0)), it was talking about the *Tales of Zestiria The X* anime. In it, it says

> It's time to switch gears and meet a new heroine in our tale and of the upcoming game Tales of Berseria. Velvet Crowe has been imprisoned on a remote island for three years but the time for her breakout has come. With revenge on her mind and demonic powers at her call, will she get what she wants or will her own vengeance create a dangerous bout of malevolence?

What I picked up on was the mention of another *Tales of* game. Generally from my understanding, most *Tales of* games are set in/on separate worlds and unless they share the same main title (e.g. *Tales of Symphonia*/*Tales of Symphonia: Dawn of the New World* or *Tales of Xilla 1/2*) are generally independent of one another.

However, as the quote mentions, Velvet Crowe is from *Tales of Berseria*. Below is a screenshot from the *Tales of Zestiria The X* that was in the Funimation email.

[image: Tales of Zestiria The X]

And below are the cover shot and screenshot from *Tales of Berseria* showing Velvet.

[image: Tales of Berseria - Cover] 
[image: Tales of Berseria - Screenshot]

While she appears to be wearing something different between *Tales of Zestiria The X* and *Tales of Berseria*, her face, hair, and arm still look the same.

So I am wondering, is there a connection between *Tales of Zestiria* and *Tales of Berseria*? Is the *Tales of Zestiria The X* anime serving as a bridge between the two?

Comment: Tales of Berseria takes Place 1.000 years before Tales of Zestiria.

& an Anime is not complete without Time Travel shenanigans

Answer (score 2):

Tales of Berseria took places thousand of years before Zestiria during the time where human could still see Seraph (which during the time are called Malaks who descended from the heaven in droves after some sort of ritual during the Scarlet night).

The anime most likely try to connect the two by showing the origins of Hellions (Daemons as they called it during Berseria) and how Malaks develop emotion to become Seraphs of the Zestiria timeline. and as the episode 5 title suggest the Beginning of the Calamity.

P/S She wears some sorts of prison robe. she got back in gears after plundering what looks to be the prison Armory