# Can the Tales of Games be grouped storyline-wise?

Tags: tales-of-the-abyss, tales-of-zestiria, tales-of-berseria, tales-of-phantasia

While I was reading up on Dhaos in order to write/answer a question, I believed that the only continuation to *Tales of Phantasia* was *Tales of Phantasia: Narikiri Dungeon*. However, as I continued to read I began to spot some mentions to *Tales of Symphonia*, for instance Derris-Kharlan (the world Dhaos came from) is a third world in Tales of Symphonia and what is described on its [wikia page](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Derris-Kharlan#Tales_of_Symphonia) is

> 4,000 years prior to the events of Tales of Symphonia

Now I know there are sequels to the games like:

- *Tales of Phantasia* => *Tales of Phantasia: Narikiri Dungeon*,
- *Tales of Symphonia* => *Tales of Symphonia: Dawn of the New World*,
- *Tales of Xillia* => *Tales of Xillia 2*,

but I thought the connection between [*Tales of Zestiria* and *Tales of Berseria*](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/35746/1587) was a one off.

Now I am curious how all the Tales of Games can be grouped storyline-wise and what their chronological order is (i.e. when would *Tales of Phantasia* fit in with the two *Tales of Symphonia* games).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about video games belong on Arqade (http://gaming.stackexchange.com), even though there are some anime connections involved.

Comment: @ConMan game storyline is on topic

Comment: @NamikazeSheena Fair enough, my apologies. The wiki is a little unclear on that topic, but if that's the way it is I'm fine with it :)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's official, but I also found some things between Tales of Zestiria and Berseria. Like in the two of them you have spirits that only one person can see in Zestiria, but is aim is for the humans to see the spirits and co exist with them. And in Berseria, you also have spirits but more people can see them and more than that you have those spirits called 'Minouz' which are in the two games. So for me it's like if Berseria happens after Zestiria :)
But I'm interested to know if there are more than that (more than things like, you can see images of Repede from ToV in ToZ and all)

Comment: @Ise err, Berseria is prequel of Zestiria. Malakh(Berseria) become Seraphim(Zestiria)

Comment: @NamikazeSheena Yep after having played a bit more to it I finally understood that it's the other way around by since then I had totally forgotten this post. Sorry for the confusion ^^